# Javascript validation not working after filling form data

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one javascript for checking form fields. how ever its working fine if there is no value in any of the textbox. but after filling values in textboxes validation is not working. Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function validate() {
              debugger;
              var val = "";
              var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/

              var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtname.ClientID %>').value;
              var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtemail.ClientID %>').value;
              var smtpport = document.getElementById('<%=txtsmtpport.ClientID %>').value;
              var smtpsname = document.getElementById('<%= txtsname.ClientID %>').value;
              var password = document.getElementById('<%=txtpassword.ClientID %>').value;
              var confirmpass = document.getElementById('<%=txtconfirmpass.ClientID %>').value;
              var secpassword = document.getElementById('<%=txtsecpassword.ClientID %>').value;
              var confirmsecpass = document.getElementById('<%=txtconfirmsecpass.ClientID %>').value;

              if (name == "") {
                  val += "Name  not found \n";
              }

              if (email == "") {
                  val += "Email  not found \n";
              }

              if (smtpport == "") {
                  val += "smtp port no not found \n";
              }

              if (smtpsname == "") {
                  val += "smtp server name not found \n";
              }
              if (password == "") {
                  val += "password not found \n";
              }
              if (confirmpass == "") {
                  val += "confirm password not found \n";
              }
              if (secpassword == "") {
                  val += "security password not found \n";
              }
              if (confirmsecpass == "") {
                  val += "confirm security password not found \n";
              }
              if (password != confirmpass) {
                  val += "Account Passwords do not match.\n";
              }
              if (secpassword != confirmsecpass) {
                  val += "Security Passwords do not match.\n";
              }
              if (email != "") {
                  var matchArray = emailPat.test(email);
                  if (matchArray) {
                      return true;

                  }
                  else {
                      val += "Not a valid e-mail address";
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              if (val.length > 0) {
                  alert(val);
                  return false
              }
              else {
                  return true;
              }
          }
    </script>
```

and here how I called this script on button click :

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn green" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return validate();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

What did i mistake to this please help me out guys.

Comment: does second time you fill all values? email address too?

Comment: it's checks empty or not when first time click when after filling all values it's not works fine

Comment: see below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like issue is with below line of code

```
 if (email != "") {
                  var matchArray = emailPat.test(email);
                  if (matchArray) {
                      return true;

                  }
                  else {
                      val += "Not a valid e-mail address";
                      return false;
                  }
              }
```

here in case of valid email address or invalid email address you do not need to write return statement because of that you below code did not executed as function has a return statement in email condition.

```
if (val.length > 0) {
                  alert(val);
                  return false
              }
              else {
                  return true;
              }
```

Try to change your code and remove return statement from validate email condition where you are matching regular expression for valid email.

change your condition

```
if (email != "") {
                  var matchArray = emailPat.test(email);
                  if (matchArray) {
                      Consol.log('valid email');

                  }
                  else {
                      val += "Not a valid e-mail address";                      
                  }
              }
```